# Jquery Surround part of HTML with a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In JavaScript and/or jquery, I must highlight one or more parts of a string. This string can contain some tag Html.

Simple eg.

```
var str = "Hi, my name is Andrew!!!"
var search = "s And"
var tag = "strong";
```

output:

```
"Hi, my name i<strong>s And</strong>rew!!!"
```

output in html:

"Hi, my name i**s And**rew!!!"

The real problem is when there are more tag beetween search text:

```
var str = "Hi, my name <i>is</i> <u><i>Andrew</i></u>!!!"
var search = "s And"
var tag = "strong";
```

(a) The worst output case is:

```
"Hi, my name <i>i<strong>s<i> <u><i>And</strong>rew</i></u>!!!"
```

(b) The best case, Html Strict, is:

```
"Hi, my name <i>i<strong>s</strong><i> <u><i><strong>And</strong>rew</i></u>!!!"
```

Comment: The next step is delete malicious tag like <script>

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: The sample case I resolved with: **str = str.replace(new RegExp(search, "g"), function (x) { return "<" + tag + ">" + x + "</"+ tag +">"; });** But It fail with complex case.

Comment: Can you remove all markup and only left highlight span?

Comment: No, It's a different result. I need mantain the original string :-/

Comment: looks kinda like a homework question, basically you'll have to do a search within your result, to wrap the <strong> tags around the <i> 's/etc

Comment: I need it for work, to highligh a search word.